# Javascript/ jQuery solution to sum values from drop down lists in form

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, sum

Im just learning the ropes with javascript and jQuery but cant get my head around this. I have 3 drop down menus with a few products in them and each has a different value. All I want to do is have the user select one item on each of the drop downs and when they hit the submit button the values are added and a total is displayed in a text box.  I have now spent 14 hours trying to do this with no success so any help will be mostly grateful!

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried? Please post some `code`.

Comment: Thanks so much for all the help guys. I should have came here 14 hours earlier. Solutions work perfectly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its hard to know exactly what you're looking for but this attached JSFiddle does what you're describing - let me know if you want any part of it explained.

http://jsfiddle.net/FdZDP/1/

heres the gist:

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    var total = 0;
    $.each($(".summable") ,function() {
        total += parseInt($(this).val());
    });
    $("#sum").val(total)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be the gist of it:

```
$(function(){
    $('#my_form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var val1 = $("#dropdown1").val();
        var val2 = $("#dropdown2").val();
        var val3 = $("#dropdown3").val();
        var total = parseInt(val1) + parseInt(val2) + parseInt(val3);
        $("#my_textbox").val(total);
    });
});
```

You're grabbing the selected value from each of the dropdowns. Then, you add them together, ensuring that they are integers (convert to a number in some way if you don't want integers). then, you place that value into the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

For a variant of coffman's answer:

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    var total = $('.summable').toArray().reduce(function(a, e) {
        return a + parseInt($(e).val(), 10);
    }, 0);
    $("#sum").val(total)
});
```

which uses the ES5 `Array.reduce()` function to handle the summation of the values

Answer (score 0):

I want to sum the values selecting from multi-select dropdown list box and display the total in another text field ...

my html code:

```
<select   class="multi-select" multiple name="amt[]" id="amt" onChange="update_price(this)">

    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="5">5Rs</option>
    <option value="10">10Rs</option>
    <option value="15">15Rs</option>

</select> 


<input type="text" class="form-control" id="hidden" name="hidden" placeholder="Hidden" autocomplete="off"/>
```

javascript:

```
<script>

    function update_price(e) {
       var price = 0;                          
      $('option:selected', $(e)).each(function() {

       price += $(this).data('hidden');

      });
      $('#hidden').val(price);

    }

</script>
```